# keras convolutional neural network is predicting all zeros no matter what type of activation function I use

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, keras

I am new to using convolutional neural networks as well as keras. As a side project I scraped MLB player's headshots from baseball-reference. For each player I broke their image into different blocks(15x15 pixels) and then randomly put images back together and recorded whether or not the images actually fit together. My goal is to create a convolutional neural netowrk that can recognize when 2 images actually go together.

My input data is 15x30x3 (it is 2 15x15 blocks put together to make a 15x30 image) and a 1 or 0 for the target for whether or not the 2 images actually go together.

My data consists of:
0.7186 non-matches and 
0.2813 matches

I structured my model as follows:

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(15,30,3)))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X_train, y_train, 
      batch_size=64, epochs=10, verbose=1)
```

This results in:

```
Epoch 1/10
136996/136996 [==============================] - 21s 154us/step - loss: 
4.5399 - acc: 0.7183 
Epoch 2/10
136996/136996 [==============================] - 16s 117us/step - loss: 
4.5369 - acc: 0.7185
Epoch 3/10
136996/136996 [==============================] - 16s 117us/step - loss: 
4.5355 - acc: 0.7186
Epoch 4/10
136996/136996 [==============================] - 16s 116us/step - loss: 
4.5354 - acc: 0.7186
Epoch 5/10
136996/136996 [==============================] - 16s 116us/step - loss: 
4.5393 - acc: 0.7184
Epoch 6/10
136996/136996 [==============================] - 16s 117us/step - loss: 
4.5373 - acc: 0.7185
Epoch 7/10
136996/136996 [==============================] - 16s 117us/step - loss: 
4.5369 - acc: 0.7185
Epoch 8/10
136996/136996 [==============================] - 16s 117us/step - loss: 
4.5374 - acc: 0.7185
Epoch 9/10
136996/136996 [==============================] - 16s 117us/step - loss: 
4.5374 - acc: 0.7185
Epoch 10/10
136996/136996 [==============================] - 16s 117us/step - loss: 
4.5360 - acc: 0.7186
```

If I change my output layer to 
    model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
and use categorical_crossentropy as my loss the results are very similar and still basically predicting all zero's. I have also fiddled with the optimizer.

Notice that the accuracy always roughly matches the proportion of non-matches in my dataset. IE it is always predicting 0.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you for any and all input.

Comment: How many training samples do you have in total (I'm assuming ~140000, according to the number in your graph)? And have you tried to make the distribution more equal? Are you evaluating on a validation set,or purely on training data? What do you mean by "fiddling with the optimizer"?

Comment: Originally, I had a few million observations with roughly 3% matches (extremely unbalanced). I oversampled my target to obtain the 30% matches I used in this example.                                                                                    In this example, I

Comment: only used 140k training obs so I could process it locally and make sure the model is working, before I train on a virtual machine using all of the observations.                                                                                                               I have split into a training, test and validation dataset but the accuracy reported above is on the training. When I predict on the test set, the predictions will be all of the same class.

Comment: by fiddling with the optimizer, I meant that I have tried using adam, SGD etc.

Answer (score 0):

In line with @dennlinger 's comment, you should check if your classes are imbalanced. If they are, try to have similar number of samples or you need to use class weights.

In your case, you have two classes, weights can be calculated easily like this: `weight_0 = (total number of samples) / (samples with zero)` and `weight_1 = (total number of samples) / (samples with one)`

Then, add `class_weight` parameter in your `fit` function. You can follow [this answer](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/13496)

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I tried manipulating the class_weight parameters and still got all training accuracies of .7186. Still predicting all zeros.